# How to create a custom WPF interface to my Setup Project?

Tags: c#, wpf, setup-project

In my company we are using `NSIS` to develop our installers, however, the `NSIS` tool is so hard to maintenance and develop.

We are searching how to develop the installer using `Visual Studio`, but we would like to create our own custom interface with `WPF` for the `Setup Project`. Is it possible?

If it is, how could I do this?

P.S.: I don't know if it could matter, but our installer need to take a lot of `dlls`, create registry keys, install and start `Services`, run `database scripts`.

Comment: Why not use [WIX](http://wixtoolset.org/) ?

Comment: @Exxoff I will read about it. Thank you ^^

Comment: @Exxoff Is it possible to create an custom interface with WPF and use together WIX?

Comment: I don't know, actually. You'll need to read the documentation. :) Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

#### Google is your friend...

For standard setup project with custom WPF screens, there are several tutorials [out there](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=visual%20studio%20msi%20custom%20wpf&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3Aen-US%3Aofficial&client=firefox-a):

- [Tutorial](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dpatra/create-setup-and-deployment-of-wpf-application-step-by-step/)

**The MSDN documentation:**

- [Role based installer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa371367)
- [Customization of installer](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windows_installer_team/archive/2005/07/23/442584.aspx)

**Alternatives**

As comments said, there is also [Wix](http://wixtoolset.org/) or [Inno setup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php).

If you want to keep it full c#, you wan try [Wix#](https://wixsharp.codeplex.com/) (MIT license).

Comment: Thank you by the answer, I thing that this `Wix#` is exactly what I need. I will study a little more about it.